# Is there a way to make 2-way tables with different pairs of variable in R?

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, crosstab

I am cleaning a data of a numeracy test.

Some test items are multiple-choice items, where students choose one of the choices (e.g. `a)`, `b)`, or `c)`).

In the dataset, I made new variables by converting the items into binary variables.
For example, if the correct answer is
`a)` for Item1, I made `newItem_1` by recoding `a) = 1` and `otherwise = 0` (`NA` is left as it is).

I would like to double check if the re-coding is done successfully by table-ing the original and new variables. Doing this one pair only (in this case `Item1` and `newItem_1`) is easy, but since I have a lot of these multiple-choice items, it's not efficient to write a script to table each pair one by one.

Here's my question: is there any way to make 2-way tables with each pair of these original and new variables?
I tried to do this by for loop and looked for tips online, but couldn't find a solution so far.

I extracted part of the dataframe below.

```
structure(list(ID = 1:20, gender = c("Male", "Male", "Male", 
"Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", 
"Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Female", "Female", "Female", 
"Female", "Female"), Item1 = c("c", "c", "a", "a", NA, "c", "c", 
"b", "b", "b", "c", "c", NA, "c", "a", "d", "c", "c", "c", "c"
), Item2 = c("d", "d", "d", "d", "d", "a", "a", "a", "a", "b", 
"b", "c", "c", "c", "c", "d", NA, NA, "d", "d"), Item3 = c("b", 
"d", NA, "a", NA, "d", "c", "c", NA, "d", "c", NA, NA, "c", "d", 
"c", "d", "d", "d", "d"), new_Item1 = c(1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, NA, 1L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), new_Item2 = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, NA, 
NA, 1L, 1L), new_Item3 = c(0L, 0L, NA, 0L, NA, 0L, 1L, 1L, NA, 
0L, 1L, NA, NA, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-20L))
```

Many thanks in advance.

Shun

For a pair, I just type:
library(janitor)
tabyl (g3, Item1, new_Item1)
and I can see my recoding is correct. But I want to loop the same tabulation through Item1, 2 and 3 (and more) in this case. So my expected output would be  something like (if I use tabyl): 
------------------- 
Item1      1     0    NA
a          #    #     #
b          #     #     #
c          #     #     #
d          #     #     #
NA        #     #     #

Item2      1     0    NA
a          #    #     #
b          #     #     #
c          #     #     #
d          #     #     #
.....
----------------------
I hope my explanation is clear.

Comment: Dear Ronak, I edited my original post. Please have a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the column names in a variable and use `Map` to loop over each pair and return the comparison table.

```
library(janitor)
x <- grep('^Item\\d+$', names(df), value = TRUE)
y <- grep('^new_Item\\d+$', names(df), value = TRUE)

Map(function(p, q) tabyl(df, .data[[p]], .data[[q]]), x, y)

#$Item1
# Item1 0  1 NA_
#     a 3  0   0
#     b 3  0   0
#     c 0 11   0
#     d 1  0   0
#  <NA> 0  0   2

#$Item2
# Item2 0 1 NA_
#     a 4 0   0
#     b 2 0   0
#     c 4 0   0
#     d 0 8   0
#  <NA> 0 0   2

#$Item3
# Item3 0 1 NA_
#     a 1 0   0
#     b 1 0   0
#     c 0 5   0
#     d 8 0   0
#  <NA> 0 0   5
```

Comment: Thank you very much Ronak. This is exactly what I wanted. I have another question.  
    `Map(function(p, q) tabyl(df, .data[[p]], .data[[q]]), x, y)`  
What does ".data" mean in this code?

Comment: `.data` is a `dplyr` term. It is used when we pass column names as string.

Comment: Thank you very much. Now it is perfectly clear.

Answer (score 1):

In case of more columns, extend the `truanswer` table accordingly. The rest remains the same. You only do one mutation using the `accros` function.

P.S.
I assume your data is in the `dforg` table.

```
library(tidyverse)
df = dforg %>% as_tibble() %>% select(ID:Item3)

truanswer = tribble(
  ~col,  ~answer,
  "Item1", "a",
  "Item2", "c",
  "Item3", "b"
)
  
fcheckanswer = function(x, col) 
  ifelse(x==truanswer$answer[truanswer$col==col], 1, 0)


df %>% mutate(
  across(starts_with("Item"), ~  fcheckanswer(.x, cur_column()),  .names = "{.col}_1"))
```

output

```
# A tibble: 20 x 8
      ID gender Item1 Item2 Item3 Item1_1 Item2_1 Item3_1
   <int> <chr>  <chr> <chr> <chr>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
 1     1 Male   c     d     b           0       0       1
 2     2 Male   c     d     d           0       0       0
 3     3 Male   a     d     NA          1       0      NA
 4     4 Male   a     d     a           1       0       0
 5     5 Male   NA    d     NA         NA       0      NA
 6     6 Male   c     a     d           0       0       0
 7     7 Male   c     a     c           0       0       0
 8     8 Male   b     a     c           0       0       0
 9     9 Male   b     a     NA          0       0      NA
10    10 Male   b     b     d           0       0       0
11    11 Male   c     b     c           0       0       0
12    12 Male   c     c     NA          0       1      NA
13    13 Male   NA    c     NA         NA       1      NA
14    14 Male   c     c     c           0       1       0
15    15 Male   a     c     d           1       1       0
16    16 Female d     d     c           0       0       0
17    17 Female c     NA    d           0      NA       0
18    18 Female c     NA    d           0      NA       0
19    19 Female c     d     d           0       0       0
20    20 Female c     d     d           0       0       0
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer Marek. I didn't know the `across` function.

Comment: `accros` performs the `fcheckanswer` function on all columns whose names begin with "Item" (`starts_with("Item")`).  The `.x` parameter is the vector of values ​​from the current column, the `cur_column ()` parameter is the name of the current column.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you don't want to use the base r table function? It looks like you would get what you want from:

```
table(g3$Item1, g3$new_Item1, useNA="always")
```

Where g3 is the dataframe you defined above.

If you want to define the pairs a different way for a loop, I suggest something like:

```
x = "Item1"
table(g3[, colnames(g3)==x], g3[, colnames(g3)==paste0("new_",x)], useNA="always")
```

Where x is your loop variable. You can compare "x" vs "new_x" this way without manually pairing each column in the table function. You just need to feed in a list for x into your loop.

The output is:

```
        0  1 <NA>
  a     3  0    0
  b     3  0    0
  c     0 11    0
  d     1  0    0
  <NA>  0  0    2
```